# Parsing date from html tags

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

How can we parse any date when html tags are polluting the dates ?

**sample:**

```
<tag> Aug 22, <tag> 2021
```

**Desired output**

```
22 August 2021
```

This is just a sample. The dates can be in any format.

Comment: Are these tags always the same? Is there a pattern?

Comment: No. Pattern can be different

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s = '<tag> Aug 22, <tag> 2021'
>>> print(datetime.strptime(s.replace('<tag> ', ''), '%b %d, %Y'))
2021-08-22 00:00:00
>>>
```